# How to retrieve unsaved tabs on Azure Data Studio?

Tags: azure-data-studio

How to retrieve unsaved tabs on Azure Data Studio?

I was writing a long Azure SQL script that contained a cursor and while loop. And while I was `dry-run` ning it it crashed! I had not saved my work on this tab. I would like to retrieve the script so I do not have spend time writing it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the unsaved sql script using below query

```sql
USE  <databaseName>
    
SELECT
    execquery.last_execution_time AS [Date Time]
    , execsql.TEXT AS [Script]
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS execquery
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(execquery.sql_handle) AS execsql
    ORDER BY execquery.last_execution_time DESC
```

It will retrieve the unsaved script

[image]

Along with that as per [this](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/14602) In the latest version Azure data studio above issue is fixed. i.e. the unsaved scripts are not closed by ADS if it closed with any crashes. Try to check the version of ADS.